# Html5 Canvas overlay

Tags: html, canvas, bitmap, overlay

Is there a good solution to draw a bitmap with an overlay color with canvas ?

What I'm looking to do is drawing a bitmap with a unique color for all not transparent pixel.
I do not find any solution for that, and it could be usefull for me !

Thank's

Comment: I have not done it before, but I think XOR operation will do it (did this with XOR and Java applets 10 years ago).. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html Search for XOR

Answer (score 3):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/qduSR/1/)**

One way to do it is to loop through each pixel and change the r/g/b values to the value you want it. By skipping over the alpha value it will only change the opaque pixels to the color you want.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = document.getElementById("testImage");

ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 128, 128),
    pix = imgd.data,
    uniqueColor = [0,0,255]; // Blue for an example, can change this value to be anything.

// Loops through all of the pixels and modifies the components.
for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
      pix[i] = uniqueColor[0];   // Red component
      pix[i+1] = uniqueColor[1]; // Green component
      pix[i+2] = uniqueColor[2]; // Blue component
      //pix[i+3] is the transparency.
}

ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);

// Just extra if you wanted to display within an img tag.
var savedImageData = document.getElementById("imageData");
savedImageData.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: yeap. I tryed this method but it is too small for my need.

Comment: @webshaker what do you mean by too small? The above just uses an example image.

Comment: oups too slow sorry. in fact I will explain what I'm triyng to do. I'm making an editor. I want to be able to select a sprite in the screen. I've made a detection using the square arrond the sprite but it's not enough accurate. I like to draw each sprite with a specific color into a hidden buffer in order to find the exact sprite selected.

Comment: Ahh ok I understand now yeah this method is definitely a slower way of doing that.

Comment: yes :) but finnaly, reading you message, I found a cool solution. I check first the rectangle, then i'm going to read the clicked pixel into the sprite bitmap (unsing getImageData) and if it's transparent, I consider that the sprite is not selected. I've not finished yet, but it will probably solve my problem. :)