# Recoloring an image in jquery, ajax or with pure css

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, colors

I'm trying to build a wizard and I'm new to ajax and jquery. I'm just a html/css gal. I'm trying it this way since flash won't work on any apple device.  Anyway I've downloaded http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard  And will be working off of this to build my  wizard.

Essentially what I'm building is a wizard that in each step will help you build your car seat.  The problem arises that there are multiple types of colors to choose from and then multiple insert colors on top of that.  So you could pick a black seat for example, but then if you decided to purchase a seat with an insert, you can pick a variety of colors like yellow or blue or something.  There are so many seat colors + insert colors I didn't want to load that large of a selection of images into a database to pull from.

What I was considering doing was saving two separate png image files, one for the seat and another for the inserts.  If the customer chooses the seat with an insert they each are on their own z-index and then I use a css overlay to color each z-index.  The issue is can i just color the image itself without bleeding off of the image to the background or lower indexed image?  Maybe there's a better way with ajax someone knows of to select and change the color of each item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with images that are inversely transparent. then you can add color to the container's background.

HTML

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/1112z3o.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

and 
CSS

```
.img-wrap { background-color: red; width: 153px; height: 78px; overflow: hidden;  }
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reikyoushin/64uAK/)

another way is to use the HTML [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas)
(though this could hurt performance)

see related post here: [Html5 Canvas overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221816/html5-canvas-overlay)

Comment: you my friend are brilliant! Never thought about it that way.  I don't think that will solve the insert issue, but I might be able to get away with loading just those as individual images since there are fewer options to choose from for inserts than there are solid seat colors.