# overlay part of image of canvas with an alpha color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using the canvas control.
I load an image into it:

```
var cn1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
cn1.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);

var context = cn1.getContext('2d');
var width = 360;
var height = 240
cn1.width = 360;
cn1.height = 240;
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, width, height);
    DrawLines();
};
imageObj.src = '/Images/7.jpg';
```

I then overlay some grid lines using:

```
function DrawLines()
{       
    context.beginPath();
    for (var x = 0; x < 361; x = x + 24) {
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, 240);
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < 241; y = y + 24) {
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(360, y);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = '#FC5C5C';
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
}
```

Which gives me this look:

[image]

I then, after clicking a cell want to overlay with a blue color with its alpha transparency set so the User can still see the original image.

The mock up for this looks like:

[image]

I can handle the click event. What I need is the JavaScript to overlay with my semi-transparent blue color.

I found this on StackOverFlow:

```
// Loops through all of the pixels and modifies the components.
for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
      pix[i] = uniqueColor[0];   // Red component
      pix[i+1] = uniqueColor[1]; // Green component
      pix[i+2] = uniqueColor[2]; // Blue component
      //pix[i+3] is the transparency.
}
ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
```

From this link:[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221816/html5-canvas-overlay) but this would not give me what I want.  How can I achieve what I want?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `fillStyle` to a transparent color using `rgba()`, then `fillRect()` with that style set.

Using `getImageData`/`putImageData` is possible, but is slower and it requires CORS to be fulfilled in case image is loaded from a different origin than the page.

**Here is what you can do:**

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(150,150,255, 0.3)";  // last value is alpha [0.0, 1.0]
context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Tip: you can also reduce the grid line code to:

```
context.moveTo(x, 0);
//context.lineTo(x, 0);   not needed here
context.lineTo(x, 240);
```

Comment: hi, I am just testing this. Trying to keep up with ur edits :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson hehe, yeah, I tend to edit much. Just note the last change for fillRect.. (capital R) (I'll leave as it is now.. :) )

Comment: cool it works. Thanks for all ur tips. Will be able to accept answer in 2 mins

Answer (score 1):

You want to use, instead of say `#ccccff` for the `fillStyle`, use `rgba(100, 100, 255, 0.5)`, where the last number is the alpha, or opacity. It's represented as a decimal, to represent percentage; so in this case, that's 50% opacity.